# Understanding how to choose the right reaction for electrochemistry

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I am quite new here and studying a bit of electrochemistry. In the course of my studies I encountered a problem I couldn't figure out:

> A sample of iron ore weighing $\pu{0.2792 g}$ was dissolved in an excess of a dilute acid solution. All the iron was first converted to $\ce{Fe(II)}$ ions. The solution then required $\pu{23.30 mL}$ of $\pu{0.0194 M}$ $\ce{KMnO4}$ for oxidation to $\ce{Fe(III)}$ ions. Calculate the percent by mass of iron in the ore.

Having thought about this question somewhat, it is clear that I will have to use  the redox reactions for iron of

\begin{align}
  \ce{Fe^0(s) &-> Fe^2+ + 2e-} \\
  \ce{Fe^2+ &-> Fe^3+ + e-} 
\end{align}

Furthermore, seeing as the reaction is occurring in an acidic environment, I thought to make the assumption that $\ce{KMnO4}$ will dissociate into its constituent ions, leaving me with picking between either the reaction of

$$\ce{MnO4^- + 2H2O + 3e- -> MnO2 + 4OH-}$$

or

$$\ce{MnO4^- + 8H+ + 5e- -> Mn^2+ + 4H2O}$$

When it comes to the technical working of this problem I think I can sort it out, but my issue resides in finding the correct mechanism. If anyone is willing to help me out with what I am sure is a simple problem for the experienced members of this community, I would be extremely grateful.

In addition to this I was wondering if anyone could recommend a resource to learn more holistically about these sorts of reactions, as this question in my textbook is part of the challenge portion, and hence there is not as much material regarding the exact mechanisms of these processes.

Comment: I wish there was a tag called `classic` (for titration and redox reactions)